# Isuse with Changing cell color in excel based on cell value

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2012

I tried changing color of a particular cell value based on its content and I have the below code where it seems to be fine without throwing any error.

Problem is when i rul this code the debugger stops at       `xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);` and I'm not sure why the code stops here. Let me know if someone can help.

```
      foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {

           for (int j = 1; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                var cellvalue = (string)(excelWorkSheet.Cells[j, 5] as Excel.Range).Value;
                if (cellvalue == "Red")
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, j].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                }

                else if (cellvalue == "Blue")
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, j].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);

                }

                else if (cellvalue == "Yellow")
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, j].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);

                }

                else if (cellvalue == "Orange")
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, j].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);

                }

                else
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[5, j].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
                }

            }


        }

        xlWorkBook.Sheets["Sheet1"].Delete();
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: why are you deleting sheet1 of excel?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint there? Does the debugger show an error when it stops?

Comment: no it doesnt show any error.

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri - I need to delete it coz it's an extra sheet in my code... i have listed only a part of my code here

Answer (score 1):

The [Workbook.Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx) has three parameters; all optional. If you do not specify the parameter of the option they are simply taken in order.

If you do not need to specify a parameter other than the default then ignore it.

```
'expression .Close(SaveChanges, Filename, RouteWorkbook)
'in your case
xlWorkBook.Close(true);
```

That should be enough to save the changes to your your workbook and close it under the same name.